# MYSQL JOIN Query took a long time to execute

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with MYSQL JOIN query.

In order to get a lists of data, I have total 5 tables which all of them need to be join, here are the tables: (daily_activity_control_card-man, personnel_master_data, daily_activity_control_card, machine_master_data and work_sheet_machine).

Below are total rows I get with this query *`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table`*
I don't think the current total rows in each tables is going to slow down the query process. I have,

```
daily_activity_control_card-man (52818 total rows),
personnel_master_data (203 total rows),
daily_activity_control_card (8115 total rows),
machine_master_data (204 total rows) and
work_sheet_machine (19959 total rows).
```

Below are the result of EXPLAIN:

```
EXPLAIN `daily_activity_control_card-man`;
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| wo_number      | varchar(50) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sheet_no       | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| step           | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| reg_no         | varchar(12) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| start_time     | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| finish_time    | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status_shift   | varchar(14) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status_working | varchar(16) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status_man     | varchar(12) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| machine_code   | varchar(12) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| act_hours      | float       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

EXPLAIN `personnel_master_data`;
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| reg_no                     | varchar(25)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| personnel_name             | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| password                   | varchar(100) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| web_token                  | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| permission                 | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status                     | varchar(35)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| online_status              | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

EXPLAIN `daily_activity_control_card`;
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| wo_number    | varchar(50) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| sheet_no     | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| step         | bigint(20)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| machine_code | varchar(12) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| start_time   | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| finish_time  | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| note         | longtext    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| act_hours    | float       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

EXPLAIN `machine_master_data`;
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field                 | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| code                  | varchar(12) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name                  | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| specs                 | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| manufucture           | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| year_manufucture      | int(6)      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| purchase_price_dollar | bigint(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| purchase_price_rupiah | bigint(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hour_day              | int(12)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| rate_hour             | int(12)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| machine_group         | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| status                | varchar(12) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| location              | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+

EXPLAIN `work_sheet_machine`;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date_act      | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| wo_number     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sheet         | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| reg_no        | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| serial        | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| machine_code  | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description   | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| crew_est      | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| crew_act      | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| jam_est       | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| jam_act       | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| note          | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| manhour_est   | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| manhour_act   | float        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| machine_rate  | bigint(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| totalhour_est | bigint(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| totalhour_act | bigint(50)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status        | varchar(12)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The following is my join query to get data from tables.

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.wo_number
     , a.sheet_no
     , a.step
     , a.reg_no
     , DATE_FORMAT(a.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') start_time
     , DATE_FORMAT(a.finish_time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') finish_time
     , CASE WHEN a.status_shift = 'shift_shift' THEN 'SF' 
           WHEN a.status_shift = 'shift_nonshift' THEN 'NS' 
           WHEN a.status_shift = 'long_shift' THEN 'LS' END status_shift
     , CASE WHEN a.status_working = 'normal' THEN 'NN' 
           WHEN a.status_working = 'overtime' THEN 'OT' END status_working
     , ROUND(a.act_hours, 1) act_hours
     , b.personnel_name
     , a.machine_code
     , c.note
     , e.manhour_est
     , CASE WHEN a.status_man = 'CONTINUE' THEN 'C' 
           WHEN a.status_man = 'FINISH' THEN 'F' END status
     , d.name
     , d.specs 
  FROM `daily_activity_control_card-man` a 
  LEFT 
  JOIN personnel_master_data b 
    ON a.reg_no = b.reg_no 
  LEFT 
  JOIN daily_activity_control_card c 
    on a.wo_number = c.wo_number 
   AND a.sheet_no = c.sheet_no 
   AND a.machine_code = c.machine_code 
  LEFT 
  JOIN machine_master_data d 
    on a.machine_code = d.code 
  LEFT 
  JOIN work_sheet_machine e 
    on a.wo_number = e.wo_number 
   AND a.sheet_no = e.sheet 
   AND a.step = e.serial 
 WHERE a.status_man IN ('CONTINUE', 'FINISH') 
 GROUP 
    BY a.id HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
```

Is there anything I could to to execute the query faster?

I tried to add this condition to the query `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(a.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d') between '2018-07-09' AND '2018-08-09'` but still, it takes 45 seconds according to phpmyadmin info to get 2500+ rows.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: try to do EXPLAIN query and give indexes to reduce number of computed rows.

Comment: Pardon me, what do you mean by explain? I already added index on wo_number, sheet_no and step to these 5 tables.

Comment: are all the tables correctly keyed? You say you have indexes on 3 columns but you are using different columns in the join conditions

Comment: try to execute EXPLAIN (YOUR_QUERY) and see what are key used to compute query.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html

Comment: replace count(*) with count(1) to speed up your query

Comment: @RamRaider I see, I'm editing the post. thanks.

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Tried what you suggested but still no luck.

Comment: in the table `work_sheet_machine` it looks like there ought to be keys on `wo_number`, `sheet` and `serial`

Comment: As an aside, I think its stupidly dangerous to include '-' in column/table identifiers

Comment: @RamRaider ok, let me try to add those column to table index

Comment: also in `daily_activity_control_card-man` require a key on `reg_no`

Comment: @Strawberry Pardon me, but I don't see this character '-' in my query..

Comment: the table is called `daily_activity_control_card-man` - the `-` character should not be used in table or column names. Incidentally there may be other tables requiring indexing - I think you need to look more closely at this

Comment: Thank you!! OMG, adding indexes solved the problem! Showing without BETWEEN condition dropped from hundred of seconds to 0.0014 seconds! Again, thank you so much Guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(a.start_time, '%Y-%m-%d') between '2018-07-09' AND '2018-08-09'
```

cannot use an index, but this can...

```
WHERE a.start_time BETWEEN '2018-07-09 00:00:00' AND '2018-08-09 23:59:59'
```